# Memory Leak in Unknown Field from meminfo

Tags: ram

I am loosing about 18k every five minutes in the Unknown Field.  Any ideas what this could be and how to debug it?

Thanks!

```
Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 444373583 Realtime: 444373583

** MEMINFO in pid 4758 [org.domain.activity] **
                   Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap        0        0        0        0    13492    12878      613
  Dalvik Heap     6983     6912        0        0     8932     7183     1749
 Dalvik Other     1761     1620        0        0                       
        Stack      192      192        0        0
       Ashmem        7        0        0        0                       
    Other dev      192      188        4        0
     .so mmap     2996     2284       88        0                       
    .apk mmap       53        0       12        0                       
    .ttf mmap        7        0        0        0                       
    .dex mmap      896        8      544        0                       
   Other mmap        7        4        0        0
      Unknown    12018    11992        0        0 
        TOTAL    25112    23200      648        0    22424    20061     2362

 Objects
               Views:       26         ViewRootImpl:        1
         AppContexts:        3           Activities:        1
              Assets:        3        AssetManagers:        3
       Local Binders:        7        Proxy Binders:       16
    Death Recipients:        0
     OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
         MEMORY_USED:        0
  PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0          MALLOC_SIZE:        0


 Asset Allocations
    zip:/data/app/org.domain.activity.apk:/assets/DS-DIGIB.TTF: 24K
```

Comment: Probably belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you have any actual problem or is this purely a cosmetic/curiosity issue?